# Set DOS console mode (40 character mode)

Tags: console, ms-dos, ascii, mode

How exactly would you set the DOS console to 40 character mode (which I believe looks like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZIzCGir58Y))?

I know you can do it, as in old games like [ZZT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZZT).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *real MS-DOS*, you could use `MODE`. It *might* also work in Windows 3.x or 98's "MS-DOS Prompt".

```
mode con cols=40
```

However, you cannot do the same in Windows NT. Aside from the fact that **Windows NT "Command Prompt" is not DOS**, it just does not support 40 column full-screen text mode anymore.